# How to save all class hardcoded values in one place

Tags: vba, excel, class, enums, intellisense

I have created a class in VBA which I would like to have some pre-set values associated with it. I am new to classes, and am wondering what is the best (/a good) way of structuring my VBA code within the class object, so that I can access these default values easily as I type. An answer should preferably:

- Require relatively few additional lines of code over and above the lines which I assume will be required for the actual hard-coding of values

  - ie. something like an additional `Sub` for each hardcoded value would not be ideal
  - this is to prevent my class from becoming too cluttered
- Allow me to use intellisense in some way to access these hard coded values

It's worth noting that my main use of these hard coded values is in setting default values to variables of my class (by looping in the `initialize` event), but I may also want to access them in other portions of code

What I've tried:

Declaring an `Enum` to save my hard coded values

```
'Declarations
Private Enum startingVals
    Top = 10
    Column_Count = 4
    Left = 15
    ...
End Enum
Private topVal As Long 'variables which I assign default values to
Private colCnt As Long
Private leftVal As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
topVal = startingVals.Top
colCnt = startingVals.Column_Count
'etc.
End Sub
```

This has 2 limitations;

- Enums can only store `Long`s

  - Get around this by using a load of `Const`s instead, but then you have to remember every constant's name, plus it looks cluttered in code
- Although I get Intellisense for `.Top` and `.Column_Count`, I still have to type startingVals out in full

  - That's significantly better than having to remember all the hardcoded constant names though

Ideally I would be able to do this

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
With startingVals 'or Dim v As startingVals, With v
    topVal = .Top
    colCnt = .Column_Count
    'etc.
End With
End Sub
```

But I can't

---

Another approach would be to use a function to save the values,that way you could declare different types to just long.

```
'Declarations
Private Enum startingVals
    Top = 1
    Column_Count = 2
    Left = 3
    ...
End Enum
Private topVal As Long 'variables which I assign default values to
Private colCnt As Long
Private leftVal As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
topVal = getval(Top)
colCnt = getval(Column_Count)
'etc.
End Sub
```

Then to access the hard coded data, you have a function which takes an enum input (allowing for intellisense)

```
Private Function getval(dataType As startVals) As String
Const savedData As String = "1,2,1.17171717,hey,me,you" 'save the return values for the index specified by dataType
getval = Split(savedData, ",")(dataType) 'use datatype as a direct index of the array
End Function
```

or another way of saving the values

```
Private Function getval(dataType As startVals) As String
Const colV As Long = 10 'index 1
Const topV As String = "This is the top" 'index 2
'...
If dataType = ColumnCount Then getval = colV 'use dataType to check what to return
If dataType = Top Then getval = colV 'could use a select case too
'etc
End Function
```

- But either way we still can't access the constants unless we type the function name out.
- Also this approach requires me to update both the enum declaration at my class declarations portion, and the const declaration within the function itself, making the code harder to maintain.

#### TL;DR

What's the best method to save hardcoded values in a class object, where best is defined as

- Uses VBA intellisense (autofill) so I can quickly select the value I want as I type
- Is neat, self contained and concise within my class module, to avoid clutter
- Can preferably hold any kind (data type) of hardcoded value (although I am only using `Long` in the project I'm currently working on)
- Can be accessed without the need of typing an initialisation portion *each time* (such as a `function` or `enum` name)

  - Of course a `With` block or function equivalent would be fine, as that only requires the one instance of specifying the enum/data collection name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...to prevent my class from becoming too cluttered

I would separate the class from its initialization process adding another class lets call it `Initializer`. Initializer will know how to initialize my objects, will contain the default values and will fill my object with this defaults. But in the initializer you will have to write the assignments, no magic intellisense, but just simply write `m_` and select from the list. HTH

> Class Foo

```
Option Explicit

'variables which I assign default values to
Private m_topVal As Long
Private m_colCnt As Long
'Private m_leftVal As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Dim initializer As FooInitializer
    Set initializer = New FooInitializer
    initializer.Initialize Me
End Sub

Public Property Get TopVal() As Long
    TopVal = m_topVal
End Property

Public Property Let TopVal(ByVal vNewValue As Long)
    m_topVal = vNewValue
End Property

Public Property Get ColCnt() As Long
    ColCnt = m_colCnt
End Property

Public Property Let ColCnt(ByVal vNewValue As Long)
    m_colCnt = vNewValue
End Property

' Add Get/Let(Set) for other member variables as well
```

> Class FooInitializer

```
Option Explicit

' Default startingVals values
Private m_topValDefault As Integer
Private m_columnCountDefault As Integer
'etc.

Public Sub Initialize(ByRef fooInstance As Foo)
    fooInstance.TopVal = m_topValDefault
    fooInstance.ColCnt = m_columnCountDefault
    'etc.
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    m_topValDefault = 10
    m_columnCountDefault = 4
    'etc.
End Sub
```

> Standard module

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim f As Foo
    Set f = New Foo
    ' f is now initizlized via initializer with default values
    Debug.Print f.TopVal
    Debug.Print f.ColCnt
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use constants to define the default values in a single place.

You can then easily access them with Ctrl + Space + Default...

```
Const Default_Top = 10
Const Default_Text = "abcd"

Private m_topVal As Long
Private m_text As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
  m_topVal = Default_Top
  m_text = Default_Text
End Sub

Public Property Get TopVal() As Long
  TopVal = m_topVal
End Property
```

Comment: Ahh, that's a nice shortcut - I'm guessing you would've mentioned it if it were possible; but is there a similar keyboard shortcut just to access the list for the current class, rather than *everything*. Only then you wouldn't need the strict naming convention. Also, what exactly *is* that menu a list of? What's included and not included in it?

Comment: You could add a prefix referring to the class instead of `Default_` : `MyClass_Top`. That's the easiest way I can think of without making it harder to maintain.

Comment: I guess the `Ctrl + Space` returns all the Class/Constants from the Global context and from the current Class.

Answer (score 0):

I can't claim ownership to this solution, but when I ran into it over on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba+or+excel) it was genius enough for me to have incorporated it into quite a lot of my code since.

As used in some other object-oriented languages, accessing class-internal instance variables using a `this` construct is very familiar. The concept is extended into VBA using the example here.

I've created a class module called `CustomClass`, and within it created a **private custom type** for use only within that class.

```
Option Explicit

Private Type CustomType
    Top As Long
    Name As String
    Temperature As Double
    anotherCustomObject As CustomClass
End Type
Private this As CustomType
```

Working this way, you can create any number of internal variables of any combination of types (including objects). Accessing and initializing each of these values is now as simple as using the `this` structured variable. The `Class_Initialize` sub shows how:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    this.Top = 150
    this.Name = "Wayne"
    this.Temperature = 98.6
    Set this.anotherCustomObject = New CustomClass
End Sub
```

Set and initialize all your values to your heart's content.

Further, you can establish each with property accessors if you like. Some of these can be Read Only:

```
'--- Read Only Properties
Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = this.Name
End Property

Public Property Get Temperature() As Double
    Temperature = this.Temperature
End Property

Public Property Get ContainedObject() As CustomClass
    Set ContainedObject = this.anotherCustomObject
End Property
```

And you can create some that are Read/Write:

```
'--- Read/Write Properties
Public Property Let Top(ByVal newValue As Long)
    this.Top = newValue
End Property

Public Property Get Top() As Long
    Top = this.Top
End Property
```

Plus, you can still use the properties easily within the class using the `Me` keyword:

```
'--- Internal Private Methods
Private Sub TestThisClass()
    Debug.Print "current temperature is " & Me.Temperature
    Debug.Print "the Top value is " & Me.Top
End Sub
```

Of course, this all works when you declare an object of `CustomClass` in a different module as well.

Hopefully this helps goes a ways to helping regularize your code a bit.

(For convenience, here's the whole class:)

```
Option Explicit

Private Type CustomType
    Top As Long
    Name As String
    Temperature As Double
    anotherCustomObject As CustomClass
End Type
Private this As CustomType

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    this.Top = 150
    this.Name = "Wayne"
    this.Temperature = 98.6
    Set this.anotherCustomObject = New CustomClass
End Sub

'--- Read Only Properties
Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = this.Name
End Property

Public Property Get Temperature() As Double
    Temperature = this.Temperature
End Property

Public Property Get ContainedObject() As CustomClass
    Set ContainedObject = this.anotherCustomObject
End Property

'--- Read/Write Properties
Public Property Let Top(ByVal newValue As Long)
    this.Top = newValue
End Property

Public Property Get Top() As Long
    Top = this.Top
End Property

'--- Internal Private Methods
Private Sub TestThisClass()
    Debug.Print "current temperature is " & Me.Temperature
    Debug.Print "the Top value is " & Me.Top
End Sub
```